# Property binding not working for [routerlink] ANGULAR

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to create generic url for my menu from db

If I hard code the router link for example with the value memo then the application works

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let menu of contractMenus"><a [routerLink]="['memo']">{{ menu.facetName }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

However if I want to make it generic like so

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let menu of contractMenus"><a [routerLink]="['{{ menu.facetUrl }}']">{{ menu.facetName }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I get stuck on Loading....   And nothing happens I do not understand why or how I can fix this issue.

Comment: If you open the developer console, you'll probably see an error which gives you a hint about the issue. (Answer below anyway)

Comment: @GaëlJ when I right click in chrome and I opened the console. I did not see any errors.

Comment: You need to open the console before loading the app

Comment: @GaëlJ when I launch my app chrome starts then I can open the console.  Before I start my app I can not start the chrome console. Do you mean the console in visual studio 2019?

Comment: You can open a tab, open the console and only then enter your app URL to navigate to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem is quite simple.

Due to the binding with `[]` you don't need the string interpolation for the more generic approach ;)

If you change it, like following, it should work:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let menu of contractMenus"><a [routerLink]="[menu.facetUrl]">
    {{ menu.facetName }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I did not realize that I did not need the {{}} in the binding with []. Since I am new too angular. Thank you.